# How to run the command prompt minimized?

Tags: windows, ms-dos

I'm trying to run `cmd` in min mode, like `cmd /k start notepad && exit`.

I tried `c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /k start /min notepad && exit`.

But it opens the `cmd` and then opens `notepad`. What can I do to minimize `cmd` automatically?

Comment: Are you running this from a batch file?

Answer (score 4):

If you dont want the command prompt to linger at all you can use

```
cmd /c start notepad
```

If you want to keep it a command prompt minimized under notepad you can use

```
cmd /c start /min cmd /k notepad
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Hidden Start](http://www.ntwind.com/software/hstart.html), seems to be free for personal use.

Comment: This is an ancient post, but please consider expanding the answer.  Just pointing to a product isn't considered an answer by current standards because it doesn't indicate anything about why it's a good solution or how to accomplish the solution.  Good guidance on recommending software [here](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers).  Thanks.